# how to escape special characters in the formData in jquery POST?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, regex

I want to pass $scope.data.responseFields=CustType,AddedDt. I have tried toString() to make this as string value and pass it as for data. But i see it being passed like this: responseFields=CustType%252CAddedDt

I have tried using escpace characters to supress ",". Still it doesnot work. Can anyone suggest me what exactly is wrong with this?

```
$.post(tempURL,$scope.data).done(function(oResponse, status, xhR){
        if(null!=oResponse){
             $scope.data = oResponse.result;
        }
        else
            alert("error retrieving information");
        $scope.$apply();
    }).fail(function(oResponse, status, xhR){
        alert(status);  
    });
```

Comment: have you tried `.serialize()`?

Comment: no. Let me check.

Comment: I dont think that this will work. Because in my case i am directly assigning the value to  "responseFields" and this is the only value i need to pass.

Comment: maybe `encodeURI`?

Comment: Why don't u use $http service instead of jQuery ajax!!

Comment: Is your data coming from a form or you are building it like a json object? Show you how you get the `$scope.data`

Comment: yes it works:-)

Comment: @Divya Glad could help! Please accept my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case encodeURI should work: 
`encodeURI($scope.data)`